# AWS sts usage issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I want to get all `EC2 intances/RDS` for each accounts and trying to achieve that. This moment, I am getting all of them (After call `describe_instances()/describe_db_instances()`) for just one account. I want to achieve this using `STS`, but every time I am running the command getting the error `AccessDenied` exception.

I am going to provide `Ubuntu CLI` code here:

`aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::<custom_id>:role/sts:AssumeRole" --role-session-name "Custom-Session"`

Output looks like this:
`An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:iam::<custom_id>:user/<custom_user> is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::<custom_id>:role/sts:AssumeRole`

Any ideas ?

Comment: Clearly you don't have permissions to assume the role. You have to add such permissions to your user.

Comment: Possible to make it programatically or via website ?

Comment: Yes, its possible if you have permissions to modify your user's permissions.

Comment: It looks like your role name is incorrect. `role/sts:AssumeRole` should be `role/rolename`.